# Chromium "discarding unexpected node" -- not rendering SVG `foreignObject` html markup

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs, chromium

Relevant code at :

https://github.com/kulicuu/site_000/blob/master/lib/exhibits/projects_map_000_.coffee

This renders fine in Firefox (`44.0a2 (2015-12-06)`) but Chromium (`Version 45.0.2454.101 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)`) won't show the `foreignObject` html text markup.

Errors:

`Danger: Discarding unexpected node: 
site_000__packed.js:3880 Danger: Discarding unexpected node: foreignobject
site_000__packed.js:3880 Danger: Discarding unexpected node: foreignobject`

More complete copy-paste of the quite verbose error message:

``` Danger: Discarding unexpected node: <foreignobject x=​"332.8250015258789" y=​"-1.9805557250976562" width=​"752.6111755371094" height=​"831.8334045410156" data-reactid=​".0.0.0.5">​…​</foreignobject>​Danger.dangerouslyRenderMarkup @ site_000__packed.js:3880
site_000__packed.js:1655 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0.0.0.4): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.invariant @ site_000__packed.js:1655ReactMount.findComponentRoot @ site_000__packed.js:5126ReactMount.findReactNodeByID @ site_000__packed.js:5023getNode @ site_000__packed.js:4597ReactDOMIDOperations.updateTextContentByID @ site_000__packed.js:3005wrapper @ site_000__packed.js:7151assign.receiveComponent @ site_000__packed.js:2523ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ site_000__packed.js:7275ReactChildReconciler.updateChildren @ site_000__packed.js:12759ReactMultiChild.Mixin._updateChildren @ site_000__packed.js:12539ReactMultiChild.Mixin.updateChildren @ site_000__packed.js:12514ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._updateDOMChildren @ site_000__packed.js:10628ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.updateComponent @ site_000__packed.js:10480ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.receiveComponent @ site_000__packed.js:10436ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ site_000__packed.js:7275ReactCompositeComponentMixin._updateRenderedComponent @ site_000__packed.js:9208ReactCompositeComponentMixin._performComponentUpdate @ site_000__packed.js:9190ReactCompositeComponentMixin.updateComponent @ site_000__packed.js:9119wrapper @ site_000__packed.js:7151ReactCompositeComponentMixin.receiveComponent @ site_000__packed.js:9051ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ site_000__packed.js:7275ReactChildReconciler.updateChildren @ site_000__packed.js:12759ReactMultiChild.Mixin._updateChildren @ site_000__packed.js:12539ReactMultiChild.Mixin.updateChildren @ site_000__packed.js:12514ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._updateDOMChildren @ site_000__packed.js:10628ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.updateComponent @ site_000__packed.js:10480ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.receiveComponent @ site_000__packed.js:10436ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ site_000__packed.js:7275ReactChildReconciler.updateChildren @ site_000__packed.js:12759ReactMultiChild.Mixin._updateChildren @ site_000__packed.js:12539ReactMultiChild.Mixin.updateChildren @ site_000__packed.js:12514ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._updateDOMChildren @ site_000__packed.js:10628ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.updateComponent @ site_000__packed.js:10480ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.receiveComponent @ site_000__packed.js:10436ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ site_000__packed.js:7275ReactCompositeComponentMixin._updateRenderedComponent @ site_000__packed.js:9208ReactCompositeComponentMixin._performComponentUpdate @ site_000__packed.js:9190ReactCompositeComponentMixin.updateComponent @ site_000__packed.js:9119wrapper @ site_000__packed.js:7151ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performUpdateIfNecessary @ site_000__packed.js:9067ReactReconciler.performUpdateIfNecessary @ site_000__packed.js:7290runBatchedUpdates @ site_000__packed.js:7860Mixin.perform @ site_000__packed.js:8322Mixin.perform @ site_000__packed.js:8322assign.perform @ site_000__packed.js:7817flushBatchedUpdates @ site_000__packed.js:7878wrapper @ site_000__packed.js:7151Mixin.closeAll @ site_000__packed.js:8388Mixin.perform @ site_000__packed.js:8335ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates @ site_000__packed.js:15078enqueueUpdate @ site_000__packed.js:7907enqueueUpdate @ site_000__packed.js:7492ReactUpdateQueue.enqueueSetState @ site_000__packed.js:7658ReactComponent.setState @ site_000__packed.js:16309rr.set_boundingRect @ site_000__packed.js:141later @ site_000__packed.js:158 ```

Comment: Seems odd that its complaining about foreignobject and not foreignObject. Something seems to be lowercasing things somewhere.

Comment: good eyes! thx i'll look into it [...3min later->>>>  Actually it looks like it's quoting the html markup at that point, which is case insensitive.

Comment: I've added / cpy-psted in the complete expansion of the Chromium error.